# CORS Origin with Angular

Tags: angular, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a problem with CORS Origin on Angular ... I have my Projects deploy in kluster kubernetes on DigitalOcean.

For exampl , I could use this service : http://167.172.13.45:8889 (And it works) with Postman.

My Service in Angular 8

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {

  public apiUrl: string;

  private categories:string = environment.categories;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getAllCategories(page:number){
    return this.http.get(this.categories+"/public/v1");
  }
}
```

My environment

export const environment = {
production: false,
categories: '/categories'
};

And my proxy ...

```
{
    "/categories/*": {
      "target": "http://167.172.13.45:8889",
      "secure": true,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

Could anyone discover o try to help me ? Why is not working my own project ? Any Guide to use Kubernetes from digitalocean.

Comment: Just so you know, the angular proxy only works with the ng serve development server..

Comment: :( :( , and what are alternatives ?

Comment: CORS needs to be fixed serverside.. add the correct headers. Loads of stuff to be found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem adding the following class on My SpringBoot Projects.

```
@Component
public class XClacksOverhead implements Filter {
    
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {}

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```